# EMGU CV (OpenCV for .Net) "Corrupts" image where itextsharp won't write all of it to a pdf

Tags: c#, opencv, pdf, itext

I have a simple block of code to create a pdf from an image using itextsharp.  It works fine on it's own.  However I wanted to convert the image to gray scale before copying it to the pdf.  Since I'm already familiar with EMGU, I used that to convert the image.  However, the instant EMGU touches the bitmap, itext sharp will only render a corner of the image rather than the whole thing (I've confirmed both in the debugger and by saving the new image back out that it is complete):

No EMGU:

[image: Good]

Bitmap loaded to an EMGU Image:

[image: Bad]

Below is the code, with the 3 EMGU lines commented out (compiles to "good"):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

public void Weird()
{
  //Add the unmanaged open cv folder to the path (or copy the open cv components to the same dir as the exe)
  if (!PathIsSet)
  {
    String path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
    path = String.Join(";",
      Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"C:\OpenCV"),
      path
      );
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", path);
    PathIsSet = true;
  }

  var currDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
  var bmp = new Bitmap(Path.Combine(currDir, "sampleimage-good.png"));

  //uncommenting these lines "corrupts" the image in a way where itextsharp only rights a small corner of it.
  //var img2 = new Image<Bgra, int>(bmp);
  //bmp = img2.ToBitmap();

  //even saving and reopening doesn't work
  //bmp.Save(Path.Combine(currDir, "sampleimage-good2.png"));
  //bmp = new Bitmap(Path.Combine(currDir, "sampleimage-good2.png"));

  var pdfPath = Path.Combine(currDir, "test.pdf");

  using (var outputStream = new FileStream(pdfPath, FileMode.Create))
  {
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, outputStream);
    writer.CloseStream = false;

    document.Open();
    int pageCount = bmp.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page);

    PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
    for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; ++i)
    {
      bmp.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, i);

      var img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bmp, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

      // Scale the image to fit in the page
      img.ScalePercent(72f / img.DpiX * 100);
      img.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
      cb.AddImage(img);
    }
    document.Close();
  }

  Process.Start(pdfPath);
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `img.DpiX` on the line `img.ScalePercent(72f / img.DpiX * 100);`? The percentage is the percentage of the image, not the page. A value of `100` is the same size. If you want to scale to fit the page you want something like `img.ScaleToFit(doc.PageSize);`

Comment: Yeah that was left over from desparation.